# How to get annotated classes in a set in Micronaut?

Tags: micronaut

##### I have created a custom annotation in Micronaut named: `@Consumes`

Here is my annotation Interface: `consumes.java`

> `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)` 
> `@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})` 
> `@interface Consumed {}`

- Two classes have used this annotation. They are:

> `SimpleEvent.java` 
> `@Consumed` 
> `public class SimpleEvent {` 
> `private String simpleName;`
> `private Integer simpleAge;`
> `}`
> `DemoEvent.java`
> `@Consumed` 
> `public class DemoEvent {` 
> `private String simpleName;`
> `private Integer simpleAge;`
> `}`

#### How Can I get these classes on a list with bean introspection or without bean introspection?

Answer (score 0):

I created the solution by myself:

- I Added `@Qualifier` to my annotation Interface: `consumes.java`

```java
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@interface Consumed {}
```

- And run this method in my test class:

```java
private Set<Class<?>> collectConsumedAnnotatedClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
    Collection<BeanDefinition<?>> definitions = beanContext.getBeanDefinitions(Qualifiers.byStereotype(Consumed.class));
    definitions.forEach(definition -> {
        classes.add(definition.getBeanType());
    });
    log.debug("Collected @Consumed annotated classes:[{}]", classes);

    return classes;
}
```